# ANTLR: Parse an easy grammar and ignore non-tokens

Tags: token, antlr, antlr4

I would like to parse a simple file with ANTLR4 as this one:

```
2011-02-23 20:21:22 STRONG bla bla bla bla
2012-04-21 19:23:11 WEAK blablablalba
...
```

My GrammarFile looks like this:

```
grammar TestGrammar;


// timestamp format:

fragment YEAR: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9');
fragment MONTH: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9');
fragment DAY: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9');

fragment HOURS: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9');
fragment MINUTES: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9');
fragment SECONDS: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9');

// Example for a valid timestamp: 2014-03-25 20:21:22
TIMESTAMP : (YEAR)('-')(MONTH)('-')(DAY)(' ')(HOURS)(':')(MINUTES)(':')(SECONDS);
STRENGTH : 'STRONG' | 'WEAK';


// Skip whitespace, tabs, etc..
WS : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip ;


mainRule: (TIMESTAMP STRENGTH )*;
```

Now i'm only interested in the positions of TIMESTAMP and STRENGTH for each entry. I don't want to traverse only the tokens, as my file could look something like:

```
2011-02-11 STRONG WEAK STRONG 2011-03-11 2011-03-11 2011-03-11 WEAK
```

So I would like the parser to recognize only: 2011-02-11 STRONG and 2011-03-11 WEAK.

How do I obtain those positions as clean as possible? And how do i ignore everything but my valid tokens? I tried to add this to my mainRule:

```
mainRule: (TIMESTAMP STRENGTH ~(TIMESTAMP | STRENGTH))*
```

But it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: By positions I mean: The byte position in the file (which can be obtained by token.startIndex())

Answer (score 1):

My advice: don't use a parser like ANTLR for this. In such very simple cases you are better off by simply reading the file line by line and extract the 2 fields with some usual string operations (substr() or similar). This makes the entire task a lot simpler. Always use the right tool for a job.